# Stuck with getting the program to move on after getting the value from NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Im very new to Objective c and im slowly learning by using google etc when i get stuck but ive been stuck for hours and hours with this.
Im making a basic quiz where the answers are numbers.
i have 2 arrays questions and answer i got the array to index together and NSlog shows they are right but my code just wont agree when the right answer is selected.
the answer is always wrong even thou nslogs says its right.
Thanks for any help

```
_arrayQuestions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                   @"what is johns age?",  
                   @"What is daves age ",   
               nil];


_arrayAnswers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 @"32",@"42",
                 nil];



- (void)setQuestions {

    currentQuestionIndex++;

    if (currentQuestionIndex == [_arrayQuestions  count]) {
        currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    }

    NSString *question = [_arrayQuestions           objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex];

    NSLog(@"displaying question: %@", question); 
    [_questionLabel setText:question];

    // NSLog(@"current answers: %@",[ _arrayAnswers objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex]);
}


- (void)checkingAnswers {

    // usersAnswer  = _DateField.text  ;

    answer = [_arrayAnswers objectAtIndex:currentQuestionIndex];

    // int intAnswer = [answer intValue];
    // NSLog(@"answer = : %@", usersAnswer );

    NSLog(@"answer = : %@", _DateField.text);
    NSLog(@"answer = : %@", answer);

    if ( _DateField.text == answer) {

        NSString *rightAnswer = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Correct" ];
        [_answerLabel setText : rightAnswer];

    } else {

        NSString *wrongAnswer = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Wrong" ];

        if (  [_DateField.text length] ==2 ) {
            [_answerLabel setText : wrongAnswer];
        }
}

- (IBAction)numbersPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ( [_DateField.text length] <=1) {

        NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
        _DateField.text = [ _DateField.text stringByAppendingString: number];

        [self checkingAnswers];

    }

}
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Comment: instead of checking for  if ( _DateField.text == answer) try it with  if ( [_DateField.text isEqualToString:answer])

Comment: Thanks you so much it works Cant believe how long i spent on this. i now need to figure out how to move on to the next question, good job i have no work to day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an important distinction between Objective-C objects and references and good ol' C primitives.

```
// C
int a = 2;
if (a == 2)
{
    do_something();
}
```

The previous code works, because the `==` operator checks that the value contained within the variable `a`.

On the other hand, if you do the following:

```
// Objective-C
NSString *str1 = @"Hello";

if (str1 == @"Hello")
{
    [self doSomething]
}
```

`str1` now holds the **memory address** to an Obj-C object, which holds each character of the string "Hello". If you were to print it with `NSLog(@"%p",str1)`, it'd probably show up an hexadecimal address, something like `0xC35AF3`.

With that said, the above code won't work, simply because `==` is not comparing the real **content** of the variables, but the **address** of them, since that's what `str1` is holding, an architecture dependant address pointer. In that sense, the operator `==` only would check if the string is exactly the same string, as in, they are both pointing to the same string in memory.

Your code is doing something similar, but only the Obj-C string is being stored in an array, and you're just checking it with the user's input.

In this situation, use the method `[stringA isEqualToString:stringB]`, this method checks character by character, inside the Obj-C string.

I'd suggest you to get a firm grasp on the fundamentals of C programming before going with ObjC, since you'll be dealing with them more than you think, specially if you come from an interpreted don't-think-about-memory language. Check on K&R C and the man pages.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use "==." Use isEqualToString: . "==" is testing the equality of the address, not the object itself. The two NSStrings don't have the same address because they are different NSStrings with the same value (one is your correct answer, the other is the answer submitted by the user).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant like this:

```
- (IBAction)numbersPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    _DateField.text = sender.currentTitle;
    [self checkingAnswers];
}
```

instead of

```
- (IBAction)numbersPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ( [_DateField.text length] <=1) {
        NSString *number = sender.currentTitle;
        _DateField.text = [ _DateField.text stringByAppendingString: number];


        [self checkingAnswers];


    }
```

Comment: thanks. but my answer will work only if apply @Ben Pious answer